# .htaccess redirect from old folder name to new folder name

Tags: .htaccess, joomla

I have .htaccess rule, which rewrite one folder name to new one -

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^home/(.*) profile/$1
```

The url `www.domian.com/home/abc.html` and `www.domain.com/profile/abc.html` both are work from this rule. If user directly type `...home/abc.html` to browser, is there any way to redirect automatically from `.../home/abc.html` to `../profile/abc.html` without changing anchor tag?

Any help appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your rule to:

```
RewriteRule ^home/(.*) profile/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Adding the `[L,R=301]` flags in the rule makes it so the request gets redirected instead of internally rewritten.